# In the context of resque and delayedjob, what is a worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, resque

Question - whats a worker?

That might seem like a vague and broad question, but frankly thats the extent of my knowledge when it comes to that kind of stuff.

I have a site that relies on workers for a ton of background processing of database items, I kind of stick my finger in the air to work out how many workers to provision, and really could do with putting a bit more science behind it.

I saw a guy with a screenshot that had 120 workers, our 32GB RAM box starts to lock up with around 20 workers. I did read that if I use God, my workers start up as processes, and not threads?

Any light you could shed would be much appreciated, I am yet to find a resource online that explains it to me in layman's terms.

Edit: some specifics - we're a rails 3.1 app running Resque at the moment.

Very much appreciate your reading.

Thanks,

Geoff

Answer (score 0):

A Resque worker can be thought of as a [rake task that runs forever](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/#workers). Each worker will have your rails environment loaded. You'll need to take that into consideration as you balance the number of workers with the amount of resources each worker will use.